# Jenkins e-mail notification issue / Ubuntu server issue

Tags: jenkins, email-notifications

I'm running Jenkins 1.519 on a server with Ubuntu 13.04 and I have a problem with the e-mail notification system.

When I try to get Jenkins to send an e-mail (either the test configuration button in the manage Jenkins page, or as a build step of a job) Jenkins gives me this notification: "E-mail sent successfully", but no email is actually arriving to the recipients.

Jenkins is telling me that the e-mail notifications are working properly, but nothing is actually happening when it's supposed to. No error messages are given.

Edit:

Email settings:

SMTP server: my smtp server address

Default user e-mail suffix: -

Use SMTP authentication: check

User Name: my email username

Password: my email password

Use SSL: nope

SMTP port: 25

Reply-To Address: my email address

Charset: UTF-8

Test configuration by sending e-mail: check

Test e-mail recipient: my email address.

Edit2:

So I suppose it probably isn't necessarily a Jenkins-issue, but an issue with my server? What kind of configurations are there needed on the server side to get the email-send working? Or is the Jenkins' email-system supposed to work without hassle?

Comment: Maybe you can share your email settings?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to check the **use SSL**. Here is the Email Notification set up that's working in my system. I've also tested it in Windows, mac, and linux machines and this setup works for those systems.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Need to add proper "System Admin e-mail address" in the Configure global settings of Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Linux RedHat version 6.6 and we have found the default host and port for the SMTP is not enabled in IP table, once this is enabled it started working.

Also check if the default SMTP port is enabled in the system where jenkins is installed. This could also be the reason for failed email notification through jenkins.